# Is there a way to query stored Wi-fi network keys on Windows CE or Mobile using XML Provisioning?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I'm wondering if anyone has experience getting a stored Wi-fi network key from a WinCE device. I can configure our Windows CE (Embedded Compact 7) device to connect to a Wifi network and can specify the AP name, security mode, network key, etc. by using the built-in [XML Provisioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg155011.aspx). I can also read out all Wifi settings for the device using [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737199.aspx) (also XML Provisioning). However, all the settings are returned except for the network key. I suspect this is for security purposes.

Is there a way to force it to reveal the network key, or perhaps some other way to programmatically access this stored data?

Many thanks!

Edit:

@Nicolas-R requested an example.

Here's setting the Wi-Fi settings on the device using XML provisioning (for WPA2-Personal authentication):

```
<wap-provisioningdoc>
    <characteristic type="Wi-Fi">
        <characteristic type="access-point">
            <characteristic type="MyWirelessApName">
                <parm name="Hidden" value="0" />
                <parm name="Encryption" value="6" />
                <parm name="Authentication" value="7" />
                <parm name="KeyIndex" value="1" />
                <parm name="NetworkKey" value="MyNetworkPassword" />
                <parm name="KeyProvided" value="0" />
                <parm name="Use8021x" value="0" />
                <parm name="EAPType" value="0" />
            </characteristic>
        </characteristic>
    </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

And here is how to query all Wi-Fi info from the device:

```
<wap-provisioningdoc>
    <characteristic type="Wi-Fi">
        <characteristic-query type="access-point" recursive="true"/>
    </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

Here's the response I get back from the device:

```
<wap-provisioningdoc>
    <characteristic type="Wi-Fi">
        <characteristic type="access-point" recursive="true">
            <characteristic type="MyWirelessApName"><parm name="DestId" value="{436EF144-B8FB-4863-A041-8F945A62C572}"/>
                <parm name="AdHoc" value="0"/>
                <parm name="Hidden" value="0"/>
                <parm name="Authentication" value="7"/>
                <parm name="Encryption" value="6"/>
                <parm name="KeyProvided" value="0"/>
                <parm name="NetworkKey" value=""/>
                <parm name="KeyIndex" value="1"/>
                <parm name="Use8021x" value="0"/>
                <parm name="EAPType" value="0"/>
            </characteristic>
        </characteristic>
    </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

As you can see, the NetworkKey returned is blank. I've tested this, however, to verify that the REAL network key really is stored on the WinCE device (and it is; it successfully joins the password-protected access point).

Answer (score 0):

I used to manipulate XML Provisioning for setting devices' APN, and a "problem" was also occurring with APN's password: we can only get '*' chars for security reasons according to the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737338.aspx

> Queries of the Password field will return a string composed of
>   asterisks ('*').

The behaviour you depict is not compliant with the Wifi provisioning documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737539.aspx):

> **NetworkKey**
>
> Specifies the network key in ASCII or hexadecimal. You can set or query the value. The maximum length of this value is 64 characters.
>
> Note: This parm is stored and sent as plain text. You should make sure
>   you transmit XML that contains this setting in a secure manner since
>   access to the XML provides access to the network key.

Can you provide a sample code of your tests for the provisioning query?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Nicolas. I've added example code to my original post.
The documentation you point to is for Windows Mobile; the one I linked to in my original question is specific to windows Embedded Compact, and the NetworkKey section doesn't mention the ability to query the key. I still don't have a way to query the stored password.

Comment: Sorry, your 2nd link was about Windows Mobile also. I think this is a security issue, I will try to test on a Windows Mobile to see if I got the same result (blank field).
Can you try to do a more specific query (on the parameter, not on the characteristic)?